# Presenting ViewController from UIWebView delegate

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a `UIWebView` with a delegate `id<UIWebViewDelegate>`. When I click on links in the UIWebView, I get the `NSURLRequest` object in the callback:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
- (void)presentWebViewControllerWithUrl:(NSURL*)URL{
      SVModalWebViewController *webViewController = [[SVModalWebViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL];
      webViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
      webViewController.availableActions = SVWebViewControllerAvailableActionsOpenInSafari | SVWebViewControllerAvailableActionsCopyLink | SVWebViewControllerAvailableActionsMailLink;
      [self presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
}
```

When I place this code in my main view controller, the modal web view appears, but it doesn't if I place it in my delegate. How do I make it appear?

---

#### update:

Returning `NO` from the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` simply makes my UIWebViews turn white, with no content. It seems that the callback is being called when the webviews load. I am loading locally stored `HTML` into them with `[web loadHTMLString:@"..." baseUrl: nil]`
The modal never appears.

My view hierarchy is as follows:

1. MainView

   - UIView

     - UIScrollView

       - UIWebView
       - UIWebView
       - ...

Is there a way to "bubble" up the callbacks so that I can see the event in my main view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to return (NO) when overriding your shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method.

Also, I don't see the [viewController presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES] in your code, something like this:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
    {
     if (navigationType != UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
      return (YES);

     SVModalWebViewController *webViewController = [[SVModalWebViewController alloc] initWithURL:[request URL]]; 
     webViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;  
     webViewController.availableActions = SVWebViewControllerAvailableActionsOpenInSafari | SVWebViewControllerAvailableActionsCopyLink | SVWebViewControllerAvailableActionsMailLink; 
     [myViewController presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
     return(NO);
    }
```

Comment: This method did not work for me. Perhaps there is a way to "bubble" up the callbacks to my main view controller?

Comment: [self presentModalViewController...] assumes that this delegate method is in a UIViewController class.  Run in a debugger and see what's happening.  I also edited code as you should be checking the navigationType

Comment: Hi, I am facing exactly same problem. I have already spent 2 days looking for a solution but it crashes my app. Please help me....